# How to handle initialization error occurred in constructor with no return allowed in constructor

Tags: java, c++

Since we cant return value from constructor in C++ or JAVA, if there is some error while initialising a new object then how can we possibly know it and handle accordingly?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you please provide an example or elaborate more on this?

Comment: can You clarify little bit?

Comment: Throw an exception. Or move the logic that potentially fails outside of the constructor and pass the result into the constructor.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: each initialization has a return status in my constructor. How do I return it in-case of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throw an exception and use a try-catch around the call to the constructor.

Comment: or you can use try catch block

Comment: +1, In C++, this would be the idiomatic way of signalling a construction error.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors in java are allowed to throw exceptions.

```
Person(int age, String name){
        if(age<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age of a person can not be null");
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either throw en exception or have a member var called isInitialized and set that to true if and only if the var was initialized properly.

Comment: The first option is good. The second not so much. It leaves you with objects that can have an invalid state, meaning you have to check every time you use them.

Comment: I agree juanchopanza, plus there's the extra memory required for the variable.  But sometimes you need that object, and timing issues cause it to not be initialized at construction.  The better answer would include don't do initialization that can fail in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

We can even make some function to be called by the constructor and then check the values.
However, is calling function inside a constructor safe and always possible? (Sorry for question within an answer :P)